# Jquery event.preventDefault not working with shift-click

Tags: jquery, click, anchor, preventdefault

I simply want users to shift-click anchor tags for a certain action.  The problem is the shift-clicking URL's in a browser opens the link in a new window.  So, naturally I would use `event.preventDefault()`, but in this case it doesn't seem to work at all, in any browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zZea9/

And here is the code:

```
<a href="#" class="edit">shift-click here</a>

<script>

$('.edit').click(function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('you shift-clicked');
    }
});

<script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have jQuery running in the jsfiddle. Once this is included, you should prevent default first, then check for the shift key and run the necessary code.

You should try to avoid stopPropogation unless you are indeed, intending to stop the event bubbling up the DOM. But in this example, this does not look like what you desire.

Take a look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zZea9/3/

```
$('.edit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        alert('you shift-clicked');
    }
});
```

and further reading on preventDefault:
[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: Thank you.  This does indeed work in the fiddle, so you've answered my question.  Unfortunately, the `stopDefault()` still doesn't work in the full context of my code, so I'll post it all in another question.  Thanks again for getting me a step further.

Answer (score 0):

You're not including jQuery so your click handler isn't being called.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="edit">click here</a>
```

JS

```
$('.edit').click(function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        alert("shift+click")
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fJHug/

Comment: Harsh downvote, he is correct, jQuery has not been included in the jsfiddle and therefore the click is never bound.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working jQuery code according to what you want.

```
$('.edit').click(function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        alert("shift+click");
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
});

$('.edit').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: why did you split it in separate events?

Answer (score 0):

Since you deleted your other question: The reason why the default is not being prevented in your "full code" is simple:

> SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'
>   _display, line 131 character 5

Always check your console for errors. They're the number one reason for code not working.

In this case, you forgot the `)` to close your `click()` function call.